# Saving multiple boxplots

Tags: r, save, boxplot

I've made a loop to create multiple boxplots. The thing is, I want to save all the boxplots without overwriting each other. Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```
boxplot <- list()
for (x in 1:nrow(checkresults)){
    boxplots <- boxplot(PIM[,x], MYC [,x], OBX[,x], WDR[,x], EV[,x], 
                        main=colnames(PIM)[x], 
                        xlab="PIM, MYC, OBX, WDR, EV")
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? You should (almost) never use `for` loops in R. You can use `apply` or `lapply`, but right now, I have only vague idea about the structure of your data. And once again, please don't use loops.

Comment: @aL3xa : indeed, you almost never use `for` loops in R. This is an example of when to use them instead of `*apply`. It wouldn't work.

Comment: Naaah... there must be a way to avoid loops. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to save them in some files, or save them to be able to look at them in different windows ?

If it is the first case, you can use a `png`, `pdf` or whatever function call inside your `for` loop :

```
R> for (i in 1:5) { 
R>    png(file=paste("plot",i,".png",sep=""))
R>    plot(rnorm(10))
R>    dev.off() 
R> }
```

If you want to display them in separate windows, just use `dev.new` :

```
R> for (i in 1:5) { 
R>    dev.new()
R>    plot(rnorm(10)); 
R> }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to @juba's answer, if you want to save the plots to a multi-page pdf file, then you don't have to use the `paste` command that @juba suggested. This

```
pdf("myboxplots.pdf")
for (x in seq_along(boxplots)){
    boxplot(PIM[,x], MYC [,x], OBX[,x], WDR[,x],EV[,x],
                     main = colnames(PIM)[x], 
                     xlab = "PIM, MYC, OBX, WDR, EV")
}
dev.off()
```

creates a single multi-page pdf document, where each page is a boxplot. If you want to store the boxplots in separate pdf documents, then use the `file=paste` command.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a list of the right length - it just makes things easier and is good practice to allocate storage before filling objects in via a loop:

```
boxplots <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(checkresults))
```

Then we can loop over the data you want, assigning to each component of the `boxplots` list as we go, using the `[[x]]` notation:

```
for (x in seq_along(boxplots)){
    boxplots[[x]] <- boxplot(PIM[,x], MYC [,x], OBX[,x], WDR[,x],EV[,x],
                             main = colnames(PIM)[x], 
                             xlab = "PIM, MYC, OBX, WDR, EV")
}
```

Before, your code was overwriting the previous boxplot info during subsequent iterations.